# Copying single row from multiple worksheets into new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried using the script below but keep getting reference error because the content of row 30 is formular based. Is there a way to have the script do a paste special or just the value of the cells/row

```
Sub copyrow()

    Dim Nrow As Long, Nsheet As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Worksheets.Add(before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "All Rows"

    Nrow = 30    'row to copy
    Nsheet = Worksheets.Count  'the count AFTER adding the destination worksheet

    For i = 2 To Nsheet
        Worksheets(i).Cells(Nrow, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(1).Cells(i - 1, "A")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly does *"the content of row 30 is formular based"* mean?

Comment: `Worksheets(i).Cells(Nrow, "A").EntireRow.Copy` then next line `Worksheets(1).Cells(i - 1, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Or you can assign directly with no copy/paste `Worksheets(1).Rows(i - 1).Value = Worksheets(i).Rows(Nrow).Value`

Comment: Thanks for the help. both suggestions works.